# NSOperationQueue, async task and maxConcurrentOperationCount

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am writing some network specific multithreaded code. I already have dispatch_group specific sample working. 
But I came across NSOperationQueue and wanted to give a try.

At high level my pseudo code looks like below:

1. I initialize NSOperationQueue and set maxConcurrentOperationCount as some finite number (5)
2. I associate a concurrent queue with this NSOperationQueue.
3. Then I start adding NSOperationBlocks to this queue. That syntax looks like follows:

```
{ 
    for (NSURL url in allUrls) {
        NSBlockOperation *jtOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
           [kick network download for url which is blocking in nature]) 
        }];
        [operationBlockQueue addOperation:jtOperation];
    }

//wait here till all urls are downloaded.
//Keep printing [operationQueue operationCount] after every 30 seconds 

//and url download code looks like: 
1. Initialize NSURLSession. 
2. Add NSDataTask to it. 
3. Wait till callbacks return. (success or error) (using blocking dispatch_semaphore)
4. After success/failure return.   
}
```

I was hoping the number of threads which get created would be only 5. But I can see the number of concurrent threads as 200. I suspect this all boils down to synchronous/async blocks. But I am still confused as my code block is blocking.

I also tried one simple exercise:

```
    int var = 2;
    dispatch_queue_t browseQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myqueue.msdbrowse", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    NSOperationQueue *myOpQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    [myOpQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];
    [myOpQueue setUnderlyingQueue:browseQueue];
    for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
        [myOpQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"value of i is %d",i);
            while (var != 3) {

            }
        }];
    }

     while(1) {
         NSLog(@"total concurrent queues are:%d",[myOpQueue operationCount]);
         sleep(5);
     }
and here output was total concurrent queues are 25.
```

Comment: How is `kick network download for url` blocking? Show that code.  If you are using any of the standard network operation techniques that will be an asynchronous operation.

Comment: "I was hoping the number of threads which get created would be only 5" Could it be that you are confused between threads, on the one hand, and queues / operations on the other? They are not the same thing. The difference has been discussed at length here already...

Comment: I have updated question. So, I wait in my network download by grabbing a lock and waiting for it to get signaled.  @matt: You could be right there and let me read more of it.

Comment: So you are making a new NSURLSession each time? This means you are surrendering the power of a single NSURLSession to limit the number of connections. — In my opinion you should re-ask this whole question describing what you are _really trying to do_. It sounds to me like this might be an x-y question: maybe you have made a wrong assumption about how to accomplish something and now you're wondering why your assumed solution isn't working. Instead, tell us what you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: @matt: I agree and I also know I can instead create multiple NSDownloadDataTask which is the right approach. And let us assume I am doing that. The reason I am creating multiple sessions is because of legacy code nd  have some time constrainst and that's why I have to create multiple sessions.

Comment: I understood little more about this behavior that we can enqueue as many operations as we want. But queue would execute simultaneous operations only specified by maxConcurrentOperations. So, if I don't want to enqueue more operations then I should just wait.